# Issues with Python while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am currently having issues with a while loop in python

```
! curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv -o mean_temp.txt

mean_temp = open("mean_temp.txt", "a+")
mean_temp.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
mean_temp.seek(0)
headings = mean_temp.readline().split(",")

while mean_temp.readline():
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(",")
    print(headings[0].title(), "of",  city_temp[0], headings[2], "is", 
    city_temp[2], "Celcius")
```

This code currently skips the first and every other line when printing

Current output:

> City of Cairo month ave: highest high is 34.7 Celcius
>
> City of Nairobi month ave: highest high is 26.3 Celcius
>
> City of Sydney month ave: highest high is 26.5 Celcius
>
> City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celcius

Required output:

> City of Beijing month ave: highest high is 30.9 Celsius
>
> City of Cairo month ave: highest high is 34.7 Celsius
>
> City of London month ave: highest high is 23.5 Celsius
>
> City of Nairobi month ave: highest high is 26.3 Celsius
>
> City of New York City month ave: highest high is 28.9 Celsius
>
> City of Sydney month ave: highest high is 26.5 Celsius
>
> City of Tokyo month ave: highest high is 30.8 Celsius
>
> City of Rio De Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius

Thanks for your help

Comment: You call `readline()` once in the condition, and once inside the body of the loop. You only process the output in one of those places. So you miss alternative lines.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop is not the appropriate thing to use here. Instead, use a for loop; in Python, a file can be iterated over directly.

```
for line in mean_temp:
    city_temp = line.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 2 lines in one loop and printing it once. Instead use below code in place of while loop:

```
for row in mean_temp:
    city_temp = row.split(",")
    print(headings[0].title(), "of",  city_temp[0], headings[2], "is", city_temp[2], "Celcius")
```